# Does CRL Validation happens for Root CA also?

Tags: x509

Does root CA certificate in a certificate chain will also checked for revocation status using CRL downloaded from the root CA CDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on certificate chaining engine implementation. For example, Microsoft CryptoAPI defaults to no revocation checking. Options are:

- Leaf certificate only
- Entrie chain, including root
- Entire chain excluding root

.NET wrapper `X509Chain` defaults to entire chain excluding root. Applications are responsible to configure revocation checking options when calling chaining engine. Non-Microsoft platforms and tools (OpenSSL, for example) are configurable as well and exact default behavior depends on an implementation and client configuration.